# Creating middleware for all requests and setting session variable in laravel

Tags: laravel

i am trying to set a session variable in middleware which i am trying to configure for all requests. I can`t seem to get it to work. The error is 
RuntimeException in Request.php line 905:
Session store not set on request.

Maybe i am making a mistake when registering the middleware in kernel.php ?

My Middleware code

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\shoppingChart;

class sessionChecker
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

       if(!$request->session()->has('test')){
           $request->session()->put('test','baran');
       }

       return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My kernel.php is

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\sessionChecker::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: You cannot use sessions that early within Laravel afaik. If you noticed under the `web` middleware it states `StartSession`, what you can do is wrap your routes in a group, assign a middleware there that modifies the session.

Comment: No it can be done I've just tested this in a similar setup. Not sure if it's the cause but I suggest you use caps in the classname. See http://developed.be/2013/08/21/laravel-naming-conventions/

Answer (score 0):

- `\Illuminate\Session\Store` was setted to `Request` when the request passed `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession`
- And the **Global Middlewares stack** run before **web middlewares stack**. So the `\Illuminate\Session\Store` was not set to `Request`

There two solution in this case. Depending on the purpose you want the application to execute.

- Use as GlobalMiddleWare. (All requests will be handled)

1. Put `\Illuminate\Session\Store` instance in your middleware constructor. Then you can access session store. For detail : See [Offical Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/container#automatic-injection)
2. Be careful that the `StartSession` middleware can be initialized or re-initialized from the driver session handler that you configured in `config/session.php`.

Here i'm showing how i put the current request Ip address to session using injected `Store` instance

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Class PutClientIpToSessionMiddleware
 *
 * @package App\Http\Middleware
 */
class PutClientIpToSessionMiddleware
{
    /**
     * @var \Illuminate\Session\Store
     */
    private $sessionStore;

    /**
     * PutClientIpToSessionMiddleware constructor.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Session\Store $sessionStore
     */
    public function __construct(\Illuminate\Session\Store $sessionStore) {
        $this->sessionStore = $sessionStore;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $this->sessionStore->put('curClientIp', $request->getClientIp()) ;
        $this->sessionStore->save() ;
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

- Use **web** middleware (Handle the web routes only. Not for : Console , API ....etc)

1. In `Kernel` class, in `$middlewareGroups`array. Place your middleware class name after `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession`. Then you willable to call `$request->session();` in your middleware class.

Here is how i defined web middlewares

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use App\Http\Middleware\MustBeSuperAdminMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{

    ...

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            /*
             * after StartSession handled the $request param passed to handle method,
             * at this point session has injected to Request
             * calling the request-›session) will be available to return Store instance
             */
            \App\Http\Middleware\PutClientIpToSessionMiddleware::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
        ],

        'api' => ... ,
    ];

    ...
}
```

My edited middleware class will be like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Class PutClientIpToSessionMiddleware
 *
 * @package App\Http\Middleware
 */
class PutClientIpToSessionMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->session()->put('curClientIp', $request->getClientIp()) ;
        $request->session()->save() ;
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't post code as image